# Tomcat v7 Will not run

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have a windows 7 machine and I have tried installing both tomcat 6 and tomcat 7 as a Windows Service (Using the executable). Neither of them will run. I have been researching different solutions for over a week now and have tried nearly everything, but I keep getting this error:

```
Sep 13, 2012 10:19:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap initClassLoaders
SEVERE: Class loader creation threw exception
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sun.management.VMManagementImpl.isThreadAllocatedMemoryEnabled()Z
    at sun.management.VMManagementImpl.isThreadAllocatedMemoryEnabled(Native Method)
    at sun.management.ThreadImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.ManagementFactory.createPlatformMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.createClassLoader(Bootstrap.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.initClassLoaders(Bootstrap.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:227)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:426)
```

When I try to run it in eclipse. When I try to run it by itself by clicking the start server executable, it starts loading up and about a quarter of the way through it just stops and the loading window goes away with no error message or anything. I am not sure what else to do?

Comment: It seems something related to enabling MBeans related config issue.

Comment: You can run the executable from the cmd blackbox (instead of double-clicking it) to get the stack trace of the error, if you have one.

Comment: did you set JAVA_HOME variable for system so that it can find the path when it starts up with with windows?

Comment: Yes I have set the JAVA_HOME Environment variable.. Inside the Tomcat7w configuration application I set the startup and shutdown mode to Java instead of jvm, and the server runs. However, It still will not run inside of eclipse, and I also need the mode to be a jvm..

Comment: I also ran it in the command line, and I get the same error. It cannot find the ...startup.Bootstrap.init or .main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception says this:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
      sun.management.VMManagementImpl.isThreadAllocatedMemoryEnabled()Z
```

This is saying that the call to the native method `isThreadAllocatedMemoryEnabled()` in the system class `VMManagementImpl` failed because the JVM couldn't find the native implementation of the method.

The only explanation I can think of is that the Java installation you are using to run Tomcat is broken.

Comment: I'm using jre6, which should be compatible with tomcat 7. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the jre and then re-installing tomcat. It still will not work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Check that tomcat is really using that JRE and not some other one.

Comment: Write a simple app to call`java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer` and compile and run it from the command line.

Comment: I don't know what was causing the problem, but I did a system restore to almost a month ago, and now tomcat will run. The jre must have gotten corrupt somehow. Now to figure out what needs to be updated again on my computer since I set it back so far! Thank you for the help.